# How to store data in nagios from a kafka consumer

Tags: apache-kafka, producer-consumer, nagios, nagiosxi

I am very new to the Nagios system. I have installed and up `nagiosXI` and `nagios log server` on my Linux server.
I have a Kafka cluster that has many JSON items in it. And also a consumer which can read data from it. my data is location-based. This means that the JSON consists of multiple fields which the most important field is the geolocation data and finally I want to show the store data(in Nagios) on a map.
I searched the net ([NagiosXI API doc](https://support.nagios.com/kb/category.php?id=105) and [Nagios log server API doc](https://support.nagios.com/kb/category.php?id=173)) but I didn't find any useful thing to know how to store(or send) data to the Nagios.

Comment: In my experience, Nagios doesn't really persist data. Just queries remote resources. Maybe it would be better to use some other database to sink Kafka into. For example, Elasticsearch then use kibana to show a map

Comment: "Nagios doesn't really persist data" is not categorically true. There are built in mechanisms for persistently storing performance data for example, even if they require some configuration. State changes on the other hand need some kind of scraping.